# Is GitHub API a RESTful API?

Tags: rest, github-api, restful-architecture

[GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) is great. It's quite convenient and simple at the same time.
It fits REST style at first sight. But does it actually? And why, if not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to review, `REST` has certain properties that a developer should follow in order to make it *`RESTful`*:

## What is REST?

According to wikipedia:

> The REST architectural style describes the following six constraints
>   applied to the architecture, while leaving the implementation of the
>   individual components free to design:
>
> - **Client–server:** Servers are not concerned with the user interface or user state, so that servers can be simpler and more scalable.
> - **Stateless:** The client–server communication is further constrained by no client context being stored on the server between requests.
> - **Cacheable:** Responses must, implicitly or explicitly, define themselves as cacheable, or not, to prevent clients reusing stale or inappropriate data in response to further requests.
> - **Layered system:** A client cannot ordinarily tell whether it is connected directly to the end server, or to an intermediary along the way. Intermediary servers may improve system scalability by enabling load-balancing and by providing shared caches.
> - **Code on demand (optional):** Servers can temporarily extend or customize the functionality of a client by the transfer of executable code.
> - **Uniform interface:** The uniform interface between clients and servers, discussed below, simplifies and decouples the architecture, which enables each part to evolve independently. (i.e. HTTP GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE)

## Does the API have those characteristics?

So, with all of this said, looking at the table of contents of the Github API docs that you linked to, I see, "verbs" which satisfies the uniform interface requirement, "endpoint", its served over `api.github.com` which means its a layered system, it offers some json-p callbacks which would satisfy the "code on demand" part, there is an "authentication" mechanism before using any verbs therefore it is stateless, it is presumably cacheable since that is typical of this type of architecture, and with all of this, you already have most of the characteristics of a REST API.

**Yes. its RESTful *enough* to be called a REST API.**

Comment: Does it fulfill the hypermedia constraint?

Comment: @JonathanW I would be surprised if it did, because for some reason, as Apigee has said in their discussions of HATEOAS, APIs often ignore that constraint completely, and is often misunderstood. However, it could be argued that github's HTTP redirects section is hinting at an API that can serve alternative functional endpoints in exchange for others, which isn't really satisfying the spirit of the constraint, but still isn't nothing

Comment: I was curious and took a look. They actually do provide links, though not through an official media type.

Answer (score -1):

- github: /repos/:username/:repo
- other:  /users/:username/repos/:repo - refer to:http://www.slideshare.net/apigee/restful-api-design-second-edition

I think it is RESTful Style.
But why github use first style?

Maybe RESTful is no standard.

Comment: How the url looks has little to do with whether or not an api can be considered restful..